# Do I put any kind of dash here?

Tags: american-english, dashes

If I say "This removes block breaking particles." when talking about a very popular block game (the game causes particles to appear when you break blocks), do I use a dash between the two words? If so, which dash do I use?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Joining words to make a single unit of an idea **always** uses a hyphen, but whether you need to do that is not clear from quoting just two words. If the duplicate doesn't answer your question, please [edit] to include a complete sentence. This puts your question into review where it can be reopened.

Comment: Thanks for editing, which shows the answer there does answer this. "A hyphen is used to join words in a compound construction", which is what you're making by using "block-breaking" as single [compound=multi-word] adjective.